# How can I use numpy to create a diagonal matrix from a 1d array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I am using Python with numpy to do linear algebra.

I performed `numpy` SVD on a matrix to get the matrices U,i, and V. However the i matrix is expressed as a 1x4 matrix with 1 row. i.e.: `[ 12.22151125   4.92815942   2.06380839   0.29766152]`.

How can I get numpy to express the i matrix as a diagonal matrix like so:
`[[12.22151125, 0, 0, 0],[0,4.92815942, 0, 0],[0,0,2.06380839,0 ],[0,0,0,0.29766152]]`

Code I am using:

```
A = np.matrix([[3, 4, 3, 1],[1,3,2,6],[2,4,1,5],[3,3,5,2]])

U, i, V = np.linalg.svd(A,full_matrices=True)
```

So I want i to be a full diagonal matrix. How an I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use numpy's [diag](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) function:

```
numpy.diag(i)
```

From the documentation:

> Extract a diagonal or construct a diagonal array.

Comment: huh it's that easy!

Comment: Yes, I find myself using _diag_ surprisingly often.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I get numpy to express the i matrix as a diagonal matrix like
>   so: [[12.22151125, 0, 0, 0],[0,4.92815942, 0, 0],[0,0,2.06380839,0
>   ],[0,0,0,0.29766152]]

You should use `numpy.diagflat(flatted_input, k=0)`, to `Create a two-dimensional array with the flattened input as a diagonal`

example

```
In [1]: flatted_input = [12, 4, 2, 1]

In [2]: np.diagflat(flatted_input)

Out [2]: array([[12, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 4, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 2, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```